# How do I identify respective file viewer is present in client machine?

Tags: asp.net

We have developed Asp.net web application, Here we have uploaded the DWFX file. In one if the UI we have managed the uploaded file.

In this ui user will select the file name then we have provided two options like download and view, When user clicks the "download" option then file will be downloaded via browser.

When user clicks the "View" button then we have to open the DWFX file via browser. if client has installed the DWFX viewer in his machine then it is works fine otherwise it shows the blank browser screen, Instead of showing the blank screen System should tell to user like "DWFX viewer not installed this machine".

How to identify the DWFX viewer installed or not in client machine? or how to achive this requirement.

Thanks
Mayil.M

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, You don't. You just have display instruction on your site that they need the [free DWG TrueView software](http://usa.autodesk.com/design-review/) from Autodesk.

Long answer, you write an ActiveX control or a Java Applet that check if the required software if already install.  And the user would have to grant your little utility the proper permission.